# What pattern to use to remove any unknown character like the translated chinese characters into latin in text file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file to read and remove its first line and then first two columns that looks like following :

here the text data

```
> Date  Time    时间           波形         波形          波形       波形          波形     波形
> 2012-11-29    09:36:38.720    0.000000    11111111    88888888    44444444    -5222222    -111111 
> 2012-11-29    09:36:38.725    00000011    22222222    -6666666    33223322    -9888888    -333333 
> 2012-11-29    09:36:38.730    00000022    55555555    55555551    -0111111    -7777777    -888888
```

I used the following code , but nothing happens :

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^([-.\d]+)\s*?([-.\d]+)\s*?([-.\d]+)$')
ignore_pattern = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z:]*[a-zA-Z:]')
# number pattern
number_pattern = re.compile(r'[-.\d]+')

matrix = []


# open the file as readonly
file=my_fi
with open(file, 'r') as file_:

    # iterator over lines
    for line in file_:
        # remove \n and spaces at start and end
        line = line.strip()
        if not ignore_pattern.match(line):

            found = number_pattern.findall(line)
            if found:
                floats = [float(x) for x in found]
                matrix.append(floats)
```

Comment: You just want to keep the numbers of the dataframe and ignore the first row?

Comment: Yes, attention that it's a text file